# .htaccess rules for old URLs to new Prestashop site do not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to redirect old URLs to a new Prestashop site, but am not finding the right way to do it.

The old structure is either of:

**example.com/Shops/** or **example.com/epages/**

I want to redirect everything to the root of the domain. I added this at the end of the .htaccess generated by Prestashop in root directory, with no success.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Shops [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/epages [NC]
RewriteRule ^epages/(.+)$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(epages|Shops)/ http://my-domain.com/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will redirect any old URI starting with `/epages/` OR `/Shops/` to `http://my-domain.com/`